# Bind event after login

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I have made a filter called auth that check if user is logged. If is not logged it redirect on the main page but if is a call ajax? I just checked if is it. If it is i just send an json status "no-log". Now i received my json response "no-log" on my client and i would like open a modal for ask login and password. The solution that i thougth was put easily for each ajax request an if statement to check if the response status is "no-log" and show the function of modal. BUT OF COURSE is not good for future update, I'm looking for a good solution where i can bind this event and if i want on the future add other status. Any suggest?

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        if ( !Request::ajax() ) {
            Session::put('loginRedirect', Request::url());
            return Redirect::to('/');
        } else {
            $status = "no-log";
            return json_encode(array('status' => $status));
        }
    }
});
```

A example of call ajax

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function() { // delete POST shared
            var id_post = $(this);
            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure do want delete?", function(result) {
                if (result) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url:  '/delete_post/' + USER,
                        data: { id_post: id_post.attr('id') },
                        beforeSend: function(request) {
                            return request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", $("meta[name='token']").attr('content'));
                        },
                        success: function(response) {
                            if (response.status == "success") {
                                id_post.parents('div.shared_box').fadeOut();
                            }
                        },
                         error: function(){
                           alert('error ajax');
                        }

                    }); 

                } else {
                    console.log("close");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Why do you say it is not a good solution for future update?

Comment: because i have more then hundred call ajax on my application, i should put the check in every function? I hope there is some quick solution.

Comment: I don't know if there the concept of 'filters' exists in Javascript. Of course if you use an Ajax API you can override one of its callback. Can you post here one of your basic Ajax call?

Comment: Thank you for your help, i just edit my post with an example of call ajax that i have on my project, can you do some example please. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 10 days of exploring an idea I found a way to *override* ajax comportment:

It just need you replace every `$.ajax()` by a custom one.

If I re-use your code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function() { // delete POST shared
    var id_post = $(this);
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure do want delete?", function(result) {
        if (result) {
            myCustomAjax({ // In place of $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                ...
```

Then this custom function allow you to add some action before or after each ajax callback:

For instance checking the JSON return value in order to decide if I trigger the success callback or I show a warning:

```
function myCustomAjax(options) {    
    var temporaryVariable = options.success;

    options.success = function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       // Here you can check jqXHR.responseText which contain your JSON reponse.
       // And do whatever you want

       // If everithing is OK you can also decide to continue with the previous succeed callback
       if (typeof temporaryVariable === 'function') 
           temporaryVariable(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    };
    return $.ajax(options);
}
```

Comment: This idea is not bad, make sense what you explained. i don't understand how myCustomajax() function can be called in place of `$.ajax({` that function doesn't make a call ajax.

Comment: @Fabrizio The last line of the custom function make the call to ajax, I think you don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

If you return a 401 for all not loggedin requests, you can use `$.ajaxSetup` to handle all ajax errors in your application.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
    if (jqXHR.status == 401) {
      window.location = 'your-login-page';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I already took a look this method but was more helpful if i could find a solution with a response json. Thank you for your help

Comment: You can't use success both in `$.ajaxSetup()` and `$.ajax()`. `$.ajax()` will override `$.ajaxSetup()`.